# Получение стрима по RTMP протоколу в Android, используя Vitamio + librtmp

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, rtmp

Я хочу проигрывать видео в Android приложении. Нашлось следующее решение [здесь](http://www.mekya.com/tag/vitamio/).
Но когда видео проигрывается более 1 минуты, я получаю ошибку и видео останавливается.

Код:

```
private String path;
private int streamId;
@Bind(R.id.streamVideoView) VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_stream);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setupVideoView();        
}

private void setupVideoView() {
    path = getIntent().getStringExtra("streamURL");
    streamId = getIntent().getIntExtra("streamId", 0);
    if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return; 
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path + " live=1");
    mVideoView.setBufferSize(2048);
    mVideoView.start();        
}
```

Лог с ошибками:

> D/HybiParser﹕ Creating frame for: [B@53686940 op: 10 err: -1
>
> I/Vitamio﹕ Info (901, 107) D/Vitamio﹕ onInfo: (901, 107)
>
> I/Vitamio﹕ Info (901, 84) D/Vitamio﹕ onInfo: (901, 84)
>
> D/HybiParser﹕ Sending pong!!
>
> D/HybiParser﹕ Creating frame for: [B@53675358 op: 10 err: -1
>
> I/Vitamio﹕ Info (901, 119) D/Vitamio﹕ onInfo: (901, 119)
>
> E/Vitamio[Player]﹕ [h264 @ 0xb8705270] sps_id (32) out of range
>
> E/Vitamio[Player]﹕ [h264 @ 0xb8705270] sps_id out of range
>
> E/Vitamio[Player]﹕ [h264 @ 0xb8705270] non-existing PPS 35 referenced
>
> E/Vitamio[Player]﹕ [h264 @ 0xb8705270] decode_slice_header error
>
> E/Vitamio[Player]﹕ [h264 @ 0xb8705270] no frame!
>
> E/Vitamio[Player]﹕ FFMPEG NATIVE avcodec_decode_video2
>
> E/Vitamio[Player]﹕ [h264 @ 0xb8705270] non-existing PPS 35 referenced
>
> E/Vitamio[Player]﹕ [h264 @ 0xb8705270] decode_slice_header error
>
> E/Vitamio[Player]﹕ [h264 @ 0xb8705270] no frame!
>
> E/Vitamio[Player]﹕ FFMPEG NATIVE avcodec_decode_video2

Помогите найти причину, пожалуйста!